# How do you have an ActionListener perform different events based on the actionPerformed?

Tags: java, event-handling, actionlistener

I have four buttons each on four different panels. If I press the button I would want the panel it's on to change color. The problem is I only know how to do that for one button and not all four. Here is my code so far...

```
public class tester implements ActionListener
{
JPanel B;
JPanel A;
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    new tester();

}

public void tester()
{
    JFrame test = new JFrame("tester:");
    B = new JPanel();
    A= new JPanel();
    JPanel cc = new JPanel();
    JPanel dd = new JPanel();
    JButton b = new JButton("ButtonB");
    JButton a = new JButton("ButtonA");
    JButton c = new JButton("ButtonC");
    JButton d = new JButton("ButtonD");
    test.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    test.setSize(600,500);
    B.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    A.setBackground(Color.RED);
    cc.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    dd.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    B.add(b);
    A.add(a);
    cc.add(c);
    dd.add(d);
    test.add(A);
    test.add(B);
    test.add(cc);
    test.add(dd);
    test.setVisible(true);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    a.addActionListener(this);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    B.setBackground(Color.PINK);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the resource and can perform action based on it If you are trying to keep a common `ActionListener`,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==b)//button b
        B.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    else if(e.getSource()==a)//button a
        A.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Please note you have to declare your buttons globally, If you have to use it inside the class,

```
public class Test implements ActionListener
{
JPanel B;
JPanel A;
JButton b;
JButton a;
```

Also you have created the implementation in a method called `tester` which should be called as,

```
new Test().tester();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymously created Action listeners instead of implementing interface in your class.

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    //method impl.
});
```

And use that to create 4 different actions.

Or you could get source of action from

```
e.getSource()
```

And then decide based on that.

Or you can skip ActionListener all the way, and use lambda

```
b.addActionListener(e -> someActionOrSomething(e))
```

Comment: This works, but then it begs the question why would you ever implement the interface when you can just do it anonymously?

Comment: @Ben it depends on "usefullness" of it. If its usefull enough (You can reuse it somewhere else) - or very long or need access to some outside resources I guess, you should consider using an inner (if its only a companion to top class) or dedicated separate listener class. I'd say you should never use a class that creates UI - to manage it as well. It would violate Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: @Ben Also, Since in this case, your tester class is public, you could have someone maliciously call actionPerformed method - but thats another issue.